# Would civilization collapse if everyone becomes invisible and mute overnight?

Tags: society, apocalypse, civilization

Set in the present day every human beings on Earth suddenly becomes invisible to the visible and ultraviolet spectrum and loss their voices due to some unforeseen circumstances in just over a couple of seconds. That's means most of the population turn blind instantly and the consequences only gets worst because this changes is irreversible. Would the civilization crumble and never recover to what it once was? Note that clothing and tatoo are opaque and the entire vocal cord missing.

Comment: If clothing is opaque, this means that people can see each other if they wear clothes?  I don't know where you come from, but here in the UK, people wear clothes most of the time.

Comment: Nowadays civilization is so connected with electronics and mobiles, so vast majority would be still looking into them, communicating via them, so a lot of them would not even notice the change :D

Comment: Apple would finally change Siri to accept text input, so at least something would improve...

Comment: @Pete: everyone is blind remember...

Comment: @user6760 - You said that everyone becomes invisible.  That's entirely different to everyone being blind.  Can you please make your question more clear in this respect?

Comment: @Pete: if light passed thru our invisible eyeballs...

Comment: Why is that any different to everyone being blind?  What significance is the clothing/tattoos?

Comment: @Pete: the way our eyes see is by picking up visible light so in other word the light do not interact with our eyes at all. As for the clothing and tatoo are just to tell the extend of the curse that's all.

Comment: Becoming invisible is largely irrelevant if everyone is also blind. See Day of the Triffids for further details

Comment: I would imagine people who are *already blind* would notice less of a change and may in fact be able to carry on as normal (provided they were blind farmers or something)

Comment: @Separatrix Not quite. Other non-human _stuff_ with eyes can still see blind people. Being invisible will help agains predators. It won't help against Predators, though...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Makin people invisible and mute is not a problem. How can you tell? Let me explain it by this method of communication called writing. I'm doing it right now to communicate with person I don't see without using my mouth.

Making all people go blind and mute is totally different problem. But, again, you give us a upper hand with "present day". I may be mute but that don't mean I'm deaf. And my phone is still working. 
So for a few day we could communicate using different methods and came up with different methods for times to come when we have power, water or food. Then people would probably die in large numbers. But as you stated that the cause last only a few second every person born after would see.

So to summarize - blind and mute world would go through the same process as Europe during black death. I think we would be set back to technology circa XIX century.

Answer (score 1):

As you stated that vocal cord will be missing in everyone, that would mean that they would need at least some way to communicate to survive, opaque clothing can be used to make hand signs visible but with most of population blind, that would not do much good either. So without even as basic thing as communication, this scenario can definitely result in diminishing of civilization. Save a few who can see.

Answer (score 1):

Civilisation ***as we know it*** would collapse, but it would quickly rebuild itself after the lootings etc. I'm not sure how we would breed and repopulate if we cannot see each other or call, maybe by writing stuff down society could communicate, but it probably wouldn't survive very long... BUT if some people survived, the few survivors would quickly overcome the weaker and start again, and in that scenario where there are a few survivors then civilisation wouldn't fall but just become smaller and perhaps more violent. Perhaps people would split into clans etc and advancement would go back a few decades?

Answer (score 0):

> Would the civilization crumble and never recover

I think that quite the opposite. It would almost annihilate civilization and then recover as there is found some good practices on how to deal with that and some new systems are built.

Security now relies on people being able to see the perpetrator. There is no way to identify each other. Maybe some identification tattoos would be required from the people and the humans without would be deemed outlaws and eliminated automatically. Communication would probably be done by hands with gloves/writing etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty certain humanity would be nearly wiped off the face of the planet in a few years time because we'd be unable to eat, drink, and protect ourselves from the elements/animals once our machines break down.

As well, there would be very few ways communicate such as by writing words on hands, making childish sounds that only use the tongue and lips (popping, snapping, clicking, etc), or banging things together. Yes, there are blind people who have adapted so that they can use something similar to echolocation, however, this wouldn't help people hunt or gather once our pre-processed food runs out meaning death for nearly all. Really I imagine the only people who could survive awhile would be the preppers, but even they would run out of food eventually and humanity would cease to exist.